# Agregar objetos al useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate

Tengo un input donde coloco X cosa, y aparecen 5 imágenes sobre eso. Si coloco otra cosa en el input, las 5 imágenes anteriores desaparecen y aparecen 5 imágenes de lo solicitado. Pero ahora requiero que no desaparezcan, sino que se vaya acumulando, en este caso que quedan las 10 imágenes.

De la consulta de la api recibo un array con 5 objetos donde cada objeto tiene una imagen.

```
[{imagen: ...},{imagen: ...},{imagen: ...},{imagen: ...},{imagen: ...},]
```

Y lo guardo en un State

```
const [imagen, setImagen] = useState([])
```

Para que se acumulen las imágenes dentro del array, es decir,que ocurra algo parecido a esto:

```
[{imagen: ...},{imagen: ...}, ... x8]
```

Estoy tratando con las siguientes formas:

```js
    setImagen(...imagen, data)
    setImagen(...imagen, [data])
    setImagen(...imagen, {data})
    setImagen([...imagen, data])
    setImagen([...imagen], data)
    setImagen([...imagen], {data})
```

Pero con ninguna consigo guardar las 5 imágenes nuevas dentro del array.
¿Cómo se puede hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te vamos a robar tu código  es muy poco el contexto, pero si agregar más objetos al array quieres intenta

```
// Imágenes nuevas que aparecen mágicamente
var imgs = [{..}..];

var aux= [...stateImgs, ...imgs]
setStateImgs(aux);
```

Si me ayudas poniendo más código mi respuesta puede mejorar

Comment: No coloqué todo el codigo porque era mucho, pero lo que propones me funciono, pero no entiendo la razon. El ...stateImgs toma lo que ya existia en el state, ¿pero porque razon tendria que colocar "...imgs" si se supone que ya estaban dentro del stateImgs?

Comment: Por qué el setState() internamente hace algo tipo `state=newVal` lo mismo susede cuando tienes un arreglo `var srr =[1,2,3,4]` si después le reasignas el valor lo que tenía lo pierde